# Como evitar el time out en genexus

Tags: excepciones, genexus, genexus15

Mi problema es que el programa me muestra lo siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y en mi codigo tengo

```
&location = getlocation('WsEgresos')
&Location.Timeout=1200
&Location.CancelOnError = 2
```

alguien me puede ayudar, lo que quiero es atrapar la excepcion y mostrar un mensaje con un Toastr, ya intente usar el try cacth de CSHAR pero aun no funciona

Answer (score 0):

Hay un comando o una rule Error_handle()

Lo probaste?

[https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?8238,Error_Handler+Command,](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?8238,Error_Handler%20Command,)

Comment: Hola, probé la solución que me dices pero sigue igual, es como si genexus no atrapara la excepción de tipo Time Out